# How to extract a specific part from text

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string-parsing

I have a string containing many words. I need to extract specific part from it. Below is the details:

Suppose, I have following string:

`x = "I am amartya ccccc amartya xxxxx amartya yyyyy amartya mohan tagore bvfvhbvbv amartya vfvbvbvfhv amartya"`

Now I want to extract the content between `amartya` and `tagore` but that should exactly be `'mohan'` i.e., the question of the occurrence is coming into picture. Ihave used regexp but that gave me content as below:
`"ccccc amartya xxxxx amartya yyyyy amartya mohan"`, but I want only `'mohan'` as my o/p.

Comment: Do you want the text between the last amartya and first tagore? Can you be more specific? What about cases such as `amartya foo amartya bar tagore oof tagore`?

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression works for your specific example:

```
r = re.search("(amartya)(?!.*amartya.*tagore)(.*)(tagore)", x)
r.group(2).strip()
```

It basically says: match a pattern starting with "amartya" and ending with "tagore" and anything between them doesn't contain the word "amartya" again.

The second group is the `(.*)` which matches anything between "amartya" and "tagore"

From the docs ([re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)):

> `(?!...)`
>
> Matches if `...` doesn’t match next. This is a negative
>   lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '`
>   only if it’s not followed by `'Asimov'`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you could start splitting at "tagore" afterwards split "amartya" and catch the last piece of string:

```
x = "I am amartya ccccc amartya xxxxx amartya yyyyy amartya mohan tagore bvfvhbvbv amartya vfvbvbvfhv amartya"

x1 = x.split('tagore')[0]
print(x1)
#I am amartya ccccc amartya xxxxx amartya yyyyy amartya mohan 
x2 = x1.split('amartya')[-1]
print(x2.strip(" "))
#mohan
```

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions